# Installing Mysql 2 gem fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to install mysql2 (version **0.4.5**) and I am using **Rails 5.0.2**, Ruby 2.3.1

I've already installed mysql server using homebrew (version 8.0.11)and started mysql  as:

```
brew install mysql
brew services start mysql
```

**Gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

When I try installing gem mysql2 I am getting the following error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/gomathi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@connector/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2

creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/gomathi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@connector/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/gomathi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@connector/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:41:
./result.h:24:3: error: unknown type name 'my_bool'
  my_bool *is_null;
  ^
./result.h:25:3: error: unknown type name 'my_bool'
  my_bool *error;
  ^
client.c:507:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:509:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:828:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:859:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:860:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:863:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:864:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:865:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:896:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1285:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
12 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

How can I get the job done?.

Comment: I have the same problem today as well (MacOS 10.13). This used to work before. Not sure what's changed.

Comment: Actually, I see you're using an older version of the gem (0.4.5 – I was on 0.4.3). Have you tried a newer version? I was able to install the current version (0.5.1) successfully (using `gem install mysql2`), but version 0.4.3 fails on my system.

Comment: Actually, I just learned that the 0.5.x release line won't work with any Rails 4 apps and some Rails 5 apps (depending on point release). Try a newer version of the gem in the 0.4.x release line, such as 0.4.10.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're installing an older version of the gem (0.4.5). I had the same issue (using 0.4.3). Installing version 0.4.10 solved this for me.

Try this:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.10
```

If that installs cleanly, you'll have to update your `Gemfile` to require this version:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.10'
```

**Don't** install a newer version of the gem (i.e. 0.5.x), they won't work with Rails 4 or older releases of Rails 5 (before 5.0.7/5.1.6) (see https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/950).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. Yes it fails at the version 0.4.5. But gets installed in the latest version.

Comment: @Gomathi please mark this answer as correct if it solved your question.

Comment: Omg! It was 2k19... Thanks, you saved my time!

Answer (score 3):

According to MySQL 5.7 document `MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH` has been enabled by default in 5.7, because of that the mysql2 not compile below the version `0.4.10` to the MySQL => 5.7

- https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/releases/tag/0.4.10
- https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/891
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-options.html

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that worked for me here was to install MariaDB, that too specifically version 10.0.x

```
$ brew install mariadb@10.0
$ brew link mariadb@10.0 --force
```

To auto-start MariaDB Server, use Homebrew's services functionality, which integrates with macOS launchctl:

```
brew services start mariadb@10.0
```

Now, the installation of mysql2 will work like a charm.

```
$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.6'
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.4.6
```

Comment: worked for me !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove everything in Gemfile.lock. After try `bundle install` again and your Project will be running ok.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by installing MySQL from dmg package
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html#downloads