# Rails error installing mysql2 (mysql2-0.3.20)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to get a rails project up and running on my local machine.  When I do bundle install

```
Fetching mysql2 0.3.20
Installing mysql2 0.3.20 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-

0.3.20/ext/mysql2
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180707-33936-1toblx7.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling infile.c
compiling client.c
client.c:367:33: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:439:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:441:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:775:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:806:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:807:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:810:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:811:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:812:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:843:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1165:56: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  mysql2rb = mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb(charset_name, charset_name_len);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:1198:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
2 warnings and 10 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.3.0/mysql2-0.3.20/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.20), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

I then follow the instructions and

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180707-34132-p3fohi.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling infile.c
compiling client.c
client.c:367:33: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:439:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:441:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:775:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:806:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:807:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:810:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:811:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:812:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:843:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1165:56: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  mysql2rb = mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb(charset_name, charset_name_len);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:1198:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
2 warnings and 10 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.3.0/mysql2-0.3.20/gem_make.out
```

I have tried the solution mentioned here

[Ruby gem mysql2 install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115126/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-failing)

```
brew install mysql
Warning: mysql 8.0.11 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 8.0.11, run `brew reinstall mysql`
```

and then

```
gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.5.2
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.5.2
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I do bundle install again I still get all of these errors

strangely if I run

```
 brew reinstall mysql
==> Reinstalling mysql 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mysql-8.0.11.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/mac/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-8.0.11.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mysql-8.0.11.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mac --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
Last 15 lines from /Users/mac/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql/post_install.01.mysqld:
2018-07-07 23:56:01 -0500

/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysqld
--initialize-insecure
--user=mac
--basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11
--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp

2018-07-08T04:56:01.743929Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) initializing of server in progress as process 35410
2018-07-08T04:56:01.746039Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2018-07-08T04:56:01.746086Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-07-08T04:56:01.746293Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.11)  Homebrew.
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mysql`
==> Caveats
We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -uroot

To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11: 254 files, 232.6MB
```

which is confusing and truthfully I don't 100% percent understand and may very well be a root of the problem, but don't know.

I have updated to the latest version of XCode and installed the Development Tools

here is what my gemfile.lock looks like

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.6.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    authority (3.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6.2)
      execjs
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.4)
    carrierwave (0.11.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    chartkick (2.0.0)
    ckeditor (4.1.6)
      cocaine
      orm_adapter (~> 0.5.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cloudinary (1.1.7)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.1)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (4.1.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dotenv (2.1.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.1.1)
      dotenv (= 2.1.1)
      railties (>= 4.0, < 5.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.11.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    font-awesome-rails (4.6.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    groupdate (3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3)
    hashie (3.5.5)
    hitimes (1.2.4)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    ice_cube (0.11.1)
    jbuilder (2.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.15)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    meta-tags (2.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.1)
    mini_magick (4.5.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.9.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.20)
    newrelic_rpm (3.15.2.317)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    oauth2 (1.3.1)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.12)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.6.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.6.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    polyamorous (1.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.6.5)
    rack-canonical-host (0.2.2)
      addressable (> 0, < 3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0, < 3)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      actionview (= 4.2.0)
      activejob (= 4.2.0)
      activemodel (= 4.2.0)
      activerecord (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.0)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (4.0.8)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.0)
      actionpack (= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (= 4.2.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.1.2)
    ranked-model (0.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.1.12)
    ransack (1.7.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.2)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.3.0)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    ref (2.0.0)
    responders (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sidekiq (3.4.2)
      celluloid (~> 0.16.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      json (~> 1.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.2)
    sidetiq (0.6.3)
      celluloid (>= 0.14.1)
      ice_cube (= 0.11.1)
      sidekiq (>= 3.0.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slim (3.0.7)
      temple (~> 0.7.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      slim (~> 3.0)
    spring (1.7.1)
    sprockets (3.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    temple (0.7.7)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.4)
    timers (4.0.4)
      hitimes
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authority (~> 3.0)
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.7)
  better_errors
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3.6)
  byebug
  carrierwave
  chartkick
  ckeditor
  cloudinary
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  font-awesome-rails
  friendly_id
  groupdate
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails (~> 4.2.1)
  kaminari (~> 0.15)
  meta-tags
  mini_magick
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.20)
  newrelic_rpm
  omniauth-facebook
  quiet_assets
  rack-canonical-host
  rails (= 4.2.0)
  rails-i18n
  rails_12factor
  ranked-model
  ransack
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sidekiq (~> 3.4.2)
  sidetiq (~> 0.6)
  sinatra (>= 1.3.0)
  slim-rails
  spring
  therubyracer
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p112

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

I also tried giving more specific commands like this answer recommended

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32869742/8239783

but I still get the same errors.

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysql_config'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180708-38248-vd681p.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysql_config
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Setting rpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling infile.c
compiling client.c
client.c:367:33: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;
                     ~ ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:439:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool res = mysql_read_query_result(client);
  ^
client.c:441:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'res'
  return (void *)(res == 0 ? Qtrue : Qfalse);
                  ^
client.c:775:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
  my_bool boolval;
  ^
client.c:806:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:807:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:810:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
    case MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH:
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
client.c:811:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      boolval = (value == Qfalse ? 0 : 1);
      ^
client.c:812:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
      retval = &boolval;
                ^
client.c:843:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'boolval'
        wrapper->reconnect_enabled = boolval;
                                     ^
client.c:1165:56: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  mysql2rb = mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb(charset_name, charset_name_len);
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
client.c:1198:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH'; did you mean 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH'?
  return _mysql_client_options(self, MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH, value);
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                     MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql/mysql.h:188:3: note: 'MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH' declared here
  MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH,
  ^
2 warnings and 10 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.20 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.3.0/mysql2-0.3.20/gem_make.out
```

Here is the log for my mysql_config file

```
mysql_config
Usage: /usr/local/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: Clang 9.1.0.9020039
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql ]
        --include        [-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --plugindir      [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [8.0.11]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib]
                plugindir     [/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/lib/plugin]
```

I am on a Mac High Sierra 10.13.4

I would love any advice I could get on it as it is driving me crazy.  Please let me know any other information I could provide to ask a better question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608287/error-installing-mysql2-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension#answer-3608756

Comment: Hello Emu, thank you very much for trying to help out.  I tried all of the solutions proposed in this post but none of them are working for me.  You can see the errors I receive when trying to simply do  brew install mysql in my post.  If you can see anything in those errors that tips you off to another problem you might suspect is causing this I would love to know.  Thank you again very much for trying to help.

Answer (score 50):

I faced the same issue when installing mysql2-0.3.21 on Mac pro.

Below mentioned solution worked for me (run the below mentioned 3 commands in the terminal pointing to your project folder):

```bash
brew install mysql

gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/mysql/include

bundle install
```

Comment: I had to point this at my Homebrew installation of mysql, but otherwise it worked for me.

Comment: In my case, the srcdir I used was /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.29/include (macOS Catalina 10.15.1)

Comment: Bless you. :tears_of_joy:

Comment: Ubuntu 20+, gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' -- --srcdir=/usr/include/mysql ; mysql_config --include to find include folder.

Comment: this saved my day, srcdir did the job

Answer (score 37):

I just ran into this problem today. mysql got updated recently, so what worked for me was:

```bash
brew install mysql@5.6
brew link mysql@5.6 --force
bundle install
```

Alternatively, I did not try this solution, but it seems to have worked for other people.

[Installing Mysql 2 gem fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909928/installing-mysql-2-gem-fails)

Comment: Hello Samantha,  Thank you so much for you help.  This allowed me to bundle install!!! but now I am getting a new error :(

        ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.40/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found

Comment: I had to do a `brew link --overwrite --force mysql@5.6 ` due to having another version on the system it seems, but this worked!

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me - **macOS Catalina**

```
brew uninstall mysql
gem uninstall mysql2

brew install mysql@5.7
brew link mysql@5.7 --force
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21'

# Gemfile
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.21'

bundle update mysql2
```

Answer (score 8):

My MacBook Pro had a disk crash during upgrade to MacOS Mojave (not pretty!), so I had to reestablish all my code projects afterwards.

One particular project proved extremely hard to get up and running and I've spent several hours today looking for a way to get mysql2-0.3.21 running for an older RoR project; Ruby version 2.1.1p76 with Rails 4.1.1.

Finally, I succeeded by following this advice: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1010#issuecomment-460257986

I did the following steps:

1. Start by removing all installed versions of mysql2 from your gemset:

   ```
   gem uninstall mysql2
   ```
2. Then install MySQL 5.6, I already have MySQL 8.0.17 installed, so 5.6 is installed as a keg only which is fine:

   ```
   brew install mysql@5.6
   ```
3. Then install mysql2 version 0.3.21 with the following command:

   ```
   gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.21 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
   ```

The OpenSSL part can probably be left out and you can change the mysql2 version number depending on what version of Rails your project is running.

After the above steps I was able to start the Rails console again and query the database:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
2.1.1 :001 > User.count
   (18.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
 => 1222
2.1.1 :002 >
```

Comment: Please, also note, that in --with-mysql-config option you may need to replace 5.6.42 mysql version with the one, brew install mysql@5.6 just installed (it was 5.6.47 for me)

Answer (score 0):

As of today Homebrew defaults to MySQL 8.0, OpenSSL 1.1 and mysql2 0.5 that work great all together out of the box. However to upgrade of my legacy applications from Rails 3.2 to more recent versions I had to setup local environment on my MacOS BigSur 11.1.

My goal was to install mysql2 gem version 0.3.x (this is only one allowing smooth migration from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2 through versions 4.0 and 4.1) together with mySQL 5.x. Both of them in turn depend on OpenSSL 1.0

Here is what worked for me:

```
// Clean-up all your faulty attempts you did before
// Homebrew does not store openssl 1.0 anymore, so I had to find alternative — openssl1.0.2t 
wget https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
brew install openssl.rb

brew install mysql@5.7
brew link mysql@5.7 --force
brew install mysql-client@5.7
// NB! Pay close attention to path where you have mysql_config and openssl 1.0 installed
gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.21 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/include
```

Voilá:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/include'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.21
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.21
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.21
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error on Debian when doing `gem install mysql2`.  The solution was to install the `libmariadbclient-dev` package.